# Adding custom css to only one lightning input in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

`Not a duplicate question, Question is 'how to apply custom css to only one lightning input without affecting css of any other lightning input elements.`

I am trying to apply custom css to lightning input but it is not working.

`HTML`

```
<lightning-input class ="lastName" name="lastName" onblur={handleEmptyValidation} >
```

`JS`

```
export default class registration extends LightningElement {
handleEmptyValidation(event) {
            let srcElement = this.template.querySelector('.lastName');
            const style = document.createElement('style');
            style.innerText = `c-registration lightning-input input {
                border-color: #54C2B2;
                }`;
            srcElement.appendChild(style);
    }
```

It works when I use `.slds-input` instead of `lightning-input input` but for some reason it gets applied to all `lightning-input`even though when I am using `srcElement.appendChild(style);`

Comment: What is the exact requirment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to change css only for 'lastName'

```
const style = document.createElement('style');
        style.innerText = `c-self-registration .lastName .slds-input {
            border-color: #54C2B2;

            }`;
        srcElement.appendChild(style);
```